# RCurl and non-Roman UTF-8 characters in URL

Tags: url, rcurl

I'm having trouble with the specific url below. The R code below generates an "invalid URL" error.

```
library(RCurl)
term <- "日本"
query_url <- paste("https://iss.ndl.go.jp/api/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&recordSchema=dcndl&recordPacking=xml&query=anywhere=", 
                       term,"%20AND%20from%20=%201887%20AND%20until=%201887", sep="")

getURL(query_url, .encoding = "UTF8")
```

But when I paste the **query_URL** into a browser . .

```
https://iss.ndl.go.jp/api/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&recordSchema=dcndl&recordPacking=xml&query=anywhere=日本%20AND%20from%20=%201887%20AND%20until=%201887
```

. . . I get the desired XML. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently encoding the single Japanese term is better for the URL:

```
library(RCurl)
term <- "日本"
term <- url_encode(term)
query_url <- paste("https://iss.ndl.go.jp/api/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&recordSchema=dcndl&recordPacking=xml&query=anywhere=", term,"%20AND%20from%20=%201887%20AND%20until=%201887", sep="")
# query_url <- Encoding(query_url) <- "UTF-8"
getURL(query_url, .encoding = "UTF8")
```